# Why my ES6 query on text does not return any hit?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created this index:

```
PUT /twitter
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_replicas": 2,
      "number_of_shards": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Next is the mapping:

```
PUT /twitter/_mapping/_doc
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "user_id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "size": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

I have inserted a document:

```
POST /twitter/_doc
{
  "name": "John",
  "user_id": "AD4G",
  "size": 100
}'
```

Now, the following query is NOT working - it finds 0 results:

```
POST /twitter/_search
{"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "name": "John"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I query the e.g. `size`, it works.

What is wrong here?

Elasticsearch 6.3

Comment: There's a huge note in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html that explains why.

Comment: @apokryfos thanx. i was reading it before and only now i realized: "When querying full text fields, use the match query instead, which understands how the field has been analyzed."

Comment: The default mapping that ES does when you don't specify one of your own is to add a property called `keyword` to each `text` field (unsurprisingly that property is of type `keyword` as well). That would allow you to have it both analysed and also use `name.keyword` to get exact matches if you need to.

Comment: @apokryfos thanx - is there a way to use `keyword` field if `term` is used, so not to specify explicitly `name.keyword` but just `keyword`?

Comment: If you have your own mapping then you need to create an additional field as a keyword and ensure it uses the same source as the `name` field. I'm not sure how to do this. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html seems to be doing this already for strings